# Using integrated GPU on OS X for GLUT applications

Tags: macos, opengl, glut

I have a GLUT application that I am running under OS X Mavericks.  I launch it from the command line, but when I do this, the automatic GPU switching kicks in and my MacBook Pro is switched over to the discrete GPU.  In this case, the integrated GPU would be good enough for my needs.  But I cannot find how I can allow the integrated one to be used in this case since I do not have an Info.plist file (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1734/_index.html for details).  I know I can disable the discrete GPU manually using a tool like gfxCardStatus, but I would prefer to solve this programmatically if I can.

I am planning on switching away from GLUT at some point, now that Apple has deprecated it's usage under OS X, but that is a lower priority for me at the moment on this project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to embed an Info.plist into the binary directly at link time.  This blog post shows how to do so: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2083/the-power-of-plist

Specifically, you create an Info.plist file for your binary and then you add the following to your LDFLAGS for your project:

```
-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist $(INFOPLIST_FILE)
```